# Boosting examples in sklearn DNNRegressor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use skflow to perform a non-linear regression using a DNN
I have successfully adapted the boston example to my needs
I load my training dataset from a CSV file like this

```
# Load dataset
us_data = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv(filename="./input.csv", target_dtype=np.float, has_header=False)
x, y = us_data.data, us_data.target

# Split dataset into train / test
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

My CSV file is organized like this :

```
INPUT-1, INPUT-2, ..., INPUT-N, DESIRED-OUTPUT
```

I would like to be able to boost some of the example using the `weight_column_name` args of the DNNRegressor class

Currently I call it like this :

```
# Build 3 layer fully connected DNN with 34,23,12 units respectively.
feature_columns = learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(x_train)
regressor = learn.DNNRegressor(
  feature_columns=feature_columns, hidden_units=[34, 23, 12], model_dir='./model')
```

I would like to add the weight of each example (as a float number between 0 and 100) as the fist or last entry of the CSV file like this :

```
WEIGHT, INPUT-1, INPUT-2, ..., INPUT-N, DESIRED-OUTPUT
```

or

```
INPUT-1, INPUT-2, ..., INPUT-N, DESIRED-OUTPUT, WEIGHT
```

Any idea of the modification that I need to make to my program to do this ? I haven't seen any use of the `weight_column_name` arg in the examples so I have no idea how to use it. Please note that I am not a Python programmer so don't hesitate to add "trivial" info 
Note that the weight of the example should not be served as input in the Neural Network